# Is it better to break down HUGE tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework-4

I am designing a financial application which saves price quotes for many securities.
Historical data can be hundreds and millions of quotes per security (and there might be hundreds and thousands of different securities).

Is it better to keep each security's quotes in a separate table, or can I use one huge table?

If I use one table I'll need to provide a unique key of symbol+time to prevent duplicate quotes, while using multiple tables will require me to only use single column  key for the time column.

Thanks

btw, I am asking this since I'm starting on Entity Framework and it seems I can't use it to create tables at runtime without adding ADO.NET, hence I need to know in advance which tables I need (and so I can't add new tables for new securities). Or did I get it all wrong?

Comment: If there ever was a time to test the supposed benefits of lightning-fast, NoSQL databases...http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases. Never used one myself.

Answer (score 4):

Tables can be [partitioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sql2k5parti_topic13) over storage, however it may not be in your interest:

> While partitioning can offer great
>   benefits, it adds administrative
>   overhead and complexity to the
>   implementation of your objects, which
>   can be more of a burden than a gain.
>   Specifically, you might not want to
>   partition a small table, or a table
>   that currently meets performance and
>   maintenance requirements. The sales
>   scenario mentioned earlier uses
>   partitioning to relieve the burden of
>   moving rows and data—you should
>   consider whether your scenario has
>   this sort of burden when deciding
>   whether to implement partitioning.

Also, if your goal would be to separate data out into separate file groups (eventually disk groups/arrays), you could probably acheive this same goal using your storage system (SAN LUN with many drives in group, RAID array with many drives to spread the load).

Your application may be fine using one table if your storage is ample and your code is tight.

Comment: +1 -- note that this is a table setting, not something that should be done manually (at least on MSSQL)

Comment: Partitioning seems to be the key since it is basically the same as having many tables, but without the overhead.

Comment: Question is: Can partitioning be dynamic based on the "symbol" of the security which is place in a master table? So if a user adds "IBM", the quotes table will add an partition for IBM quotes (there is a symbol column in the quotes table)

Comment: @Sol partitioning is based on partition functions, and yes, you have to code the ranges.  As I said in my answer, though, this is a maintenance feature, not a performance feature - indexes are for performance.

Answer (score 3):

It's always a bad idea to have procedurally generated tables. If your system is taking too long to accomplish it's goals, perhaps you should consider an [OLAP Cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube) -- that is, after all, what they're designed for.

Comment: Why? And what about having such a huge table? I'm talking 10's of gb. Would it slow down inserts and updates?

Comment: @Sol: Because it defeats the point of an RDBMS. As for table size, no, it shouldn't significantly mess with inserts and updates because any moderately recent RDBMS doesn't move the entire database structure around on inserts and updates. Also keep in mind that when thousands of tables are involved that getting the right table out of the database file/directory (MSSQL uses a single file, many other RDBMSs use directories (i.e. MySQL)) is not free and carries it's own overhead.

Comment: Depends on your physical storage array and read needs.  If you're reading one row then you might not be slowing down your writes.  If you're doing big scans and summarizing, you may run into update problems.  SQL can lock the table at lower level - the entire table isn't normally locked - stopping all other activity.

Comment: @Sol: Insert and update speed is generally determined by the amount of IO that has to take place, not the size of the table. If your clustered index (by default the primary key) is configured in such a way that inserts will always (or at least *generally*) result in the highest value in the table, then insert IO will be very low, and, consequently, fast.

Comment: @Billy: Whether or not it shifts data around is mostly determined by the clustering of the table. If you insert a value that lies in the middle of the clustered index, it *will* shift the latter half of the table "down" in order to insert the row in order.

Comment: @Adam: Usually the shift is localized though -- it's not going to shift down the entire multi-GB table. Usually the rows themselves are put into something like a deque structure, and the insert or update would only affect the "page" on which that row resides.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with a single table and an appropriate choice of indexes and constraints.

You can partition the table, but the main use for that is not for performance but for management, as this lets you remove old data and add new data partitions in a rolling way.  Except for time, this is probably not useful for you; you are unlikely to partition by stock ticker - I'm not sure what advantage that gives in managing partitions.

I'd probably consider having the clustered index be ticker (maybe an int surrogate into a ticker table or maybe just the ticker) and time.

In such a simple data model, it will kind of be indistinguishable from a dimensional model, but if you want to read up on dimensional modeling for data warehouse performance, that may be useful, particular the features/drawbacks of using an orthogonal date dimension and time dimension.  If your data is intraday, you may want to use a single datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use different tables for different securities. Please! This will ultimately cause you more problems than it solves.

If you make security the first column of the clustered index (8 bytes or fewer, use an artificial int key if necessary) and keep your indexes as short as possible your performance will be fine. Even if the engine has to do a scan to satisfy the query, security will always be supplied so it will do a range scan on the table or index.

If absolutely necessary, you can partition your table. In SQL 2008 or higher you can also create [filtered indexes](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/Filtered_Indexes_in_SQL_Server_2008_p1.aspx) that only cover a portion of the rows in a table.

Updates won't be any different problem than they would be in separate tables.

Inserts, having the security as the first column, should never really give issues either. You'll eventually end up with no mixed pages (multiple securities per page) and so inserts will perform exactly as well as they would with separate tables, because no page split will be caused by the security value (though they could be caused by other issues).